# How can I upload google tag manager and analytics to a website running fully on PHP?

Tags: php, google-tag-manager

I would like to add google tag manager and google analytics to my web app that runs solely on PHP. How can I manage to do so? The code has no `<head>` and no `<body>` on any pages, I'm wondering if - above my `<?php` declaration if I should create a head section, or what is the proper way to do so? Thank you.

Comment: Websites usually have a `<head>` and `<body>`, and just the fact that is was written in PHP shouldn't change that. Why are these absent in yours? See: [A basic HTML document](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#a-quick-introduction-to-html).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a backend language. It serves front-end code to be executed by browsers. GTM is a piece of front-end code. Backend language has virtually no influence on how the front-end is being served.

Most likely, among your PHP (and other) files on your backend, you have HTML templates, which PHP is using to serve. GTM script is supposed to be added via a  tag, which is a part of the HTML syntax. So you add your GTM  tag (which you can get from the GTM web UI) to the templates of the pages where you want it to be run. Well, you would usually just add it to the head template, but it depends on the structure of your templates.

Alternatively, if your site has a more or less recognizable CMS, it should have a native capability, or an ability to install an extension that would embed your GTM script for you.